# use jQuery to disable all clicking actions except scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a page COMPLETELY UNCLICKABLE (both right click and left click) and to display a message when someone clicks.  Since I know that this will raise lots of questions such as

> "why would anyone ever want to do this...this is stupid...then nobody
>   can navigate the site...and it doesn't protect your content
>   anyway...etc"

here is the explanation of my purpose.  I have a page that is at the moment only a graphic mockup of what the finished website will eventually look like.  No matter how many times I explain that the mockup is ONLY AN IMAGE and not a real navigable  website, they still email me to say that they cannot click on the menus and links.  Since it is a single page mockup, I want to pop up an `alert()` message (can't use a modal because you can't click to dismiss it if clicking is disabled) to let them know that they have clicked something non-functional.  I am trying to do this in as few lines of code as possible, and have the following working at the moment:

```
<script>
$('html').mousedown(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();//To prevent following the link
    alert('Demo Graphic Only...clicking on stuff will NOT work at this point.');
});
</script>
```

The issue is that when using `.mousedown` I capture the user trying to click on the browser scroll-bar to scroll down.  I was surprised by this since it is not part of the actual PAGE CONTENT but rather a part of the BROWSER...but it is catching it nonetheless.  I tried using `.click` in place of `.mousedown` however only seem to catch a normal (left) click in that case...  Does anyone know how to easily (minimal lines of code if possible) capture the left AND right click event, but allow user interaction with the browser scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $(document).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();//To prevent following the link
    console.log('Demo Graphic Only...clicking on stuff will NOT work at this point.');      
    });
```

**This Function will be called when click is made on the page , not on the Scrollbars**

Comment: This works perfectly...except the console.log() is not working.  I changed that back to alert() and everything is good now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`event.stopPropagation();`
  or
`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

For people who come across this question, an alternative approach, good especially if you need to prevent `mousedown` specifically:

Put the scrolling content in a wrapper element and prevent `mousedown` only on the inner element. Set the wrapper element to `overflow: auto; height: 100%;`